# GeoServer running on Debian Bullseye not showing the layers after system reboot

Tags: geoserver, layers, tomcat, debian

I have installed `GeoServer V.2.22.2` on Debian 11 Bullseye machine using Tomcat9.

I made some data public (layers) and after I reboot the machine, the layers and stores are not visible anymore. In the data folder I have the XML files but the server won't read them at restart.

Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that Tomcat needs to be restarted. You can do this with the following code by adapting it to your configuration:

- Shutdown Tomcat correctly with : `/opt/tomcat/bin/shutdown.sh`
- Restart Tomcat correctly with: `/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh`